# How to convert this line of code to use the backslash operator instead of inv()?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, backslash, quadratic-programming

Can anyone help me to see if it is possible to convert the following code to using the matlab [backslash operator](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) , instead of using `inv()` as I am doing currently:

```
n = 6; m = 18;
R = diag( rand(1,n) );
A = rand(m,n);
b = rand(m,1);

X = inv(R) * A' * inv(A * inv(R) * A') * b;
```

(I appreciate that in this example the result might be mathematically singular, because I have just created random matrices to demonstrate the dimensions of each one. What I am looking for is just the appropriate syntax to convert to the backslash usage - and perhaps even simplify it).

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The code comes from solving the following system of equations (they are the Lagrange conditions for a quadratic programming problem):

[image]

Rearranging them to eliminate lambda gives:

[image]

Comment: `A\b` is equivalent to `inv(A)*b` (assuming the matrix is invertible and well conditioned of course). Then just proceed piece by piece. For example, `A*inv(R)*A'` will read `A*(R\A')`. Also, are you sure you want to use the [conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html)?

Comment: @BillBokeey Thanks. I thought it shouldn't matter whether conjugate or non-conjugate, because everything is real in my case - but I will check if it affects the result. So using your method I have ```X = R \ (A' * ( (A / R) * A') \ b ) ```. There are a lot of operations here - and the matrix ```A``` appears quite a few times. Do you know if can be simplified further?

Comment: You can use the properties of the matrix inverse to try and simplify further, i.e. `inv(A*B) = inv(B)*inv(A)`, as well as `inv(inv(X)) = X`

Comment: Is there a relation between R and A? Are these for example the result of an eigendecomposition? What is this statement attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I don’t understand how you eliminate lambda. But from your information, equation (2) is already over-determined, why do you need (1)? You can solve (2) with `X = A \ b`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Both equations need to be simultaneously satisfied  (this corresponds to finding the extremum of the problem whilst also respecting the constraints). The first equation is rearranged to give X in terms of lambda. Next, X is subbed into Eq. 2, and rearranged to find lambda (this equation is now independent of X). Then finally the lambda is plugged back into the rearranged Eq. 1.

Comment: Are you sure `m > n`?

Comment: @BillBokeey I think you are correct, generally m should be < n.

Comment: Then, assuming a solution exists, the code in your first comment should work. Feel free to  run both the code in your question and this one on several examples, to check if they give you the same result. You can also start from a known problem to compare precision & time efficiency

Comment: OK, so if you have lambda in terms of A, R and b, then you can do `X = (2*R)\(A.'*lambda)`. Your definition of lambda likely can similarly be written in terms of ``\``.